# Python Decompress data returned from zip file in AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip

I have bytes returned by

```py
s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key
                    , Range="bytes=%d-%d" % (start, end)
            )
```

from a zip file stored in AWS S3.

The output is as below:

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00b\x06)T)Ih\xa4\x1c\x02\x00\x00\x08\x0b\x00\x00u\x00\x1c\x00mnt/d/repositories/Entertainment-Industry-Retailer-DataWarehouse/source_system_data/20220108/jupiter/state_format.xmlUT\t\x00\x03\x1f\xe4\xd9a\x1f\xe4\xd9aux\x0b\x00\x01\x04\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x04\xe8\x03\x00\x00\xdd\x96[o\xda@\x10\x85\xcfs\xa5\xfe\x07\x94\xe7\x96\xc4\\\x12\t\xd1D)\xb9!\x11\xd2\x02iS)\x12\xa2\tIP\xc1P\xec\xf4\xf2\xe7\xdb~3F\x90\xd6izQ1Re\xd9\x9e\x9d\xd9\xd9s\xce\xacw\xbd_\xbfT\xb5\xa3O\x1ai\xa8\x9c>\xa8\xaf\xa9"\r4V\xa8gZS\xa0\xbc6x\xefh[\x8f\xf5HU=WM/t\xa0\x13\xb5t\xac]u\xc8K\xf2C2-\xe7F1\xd7D\x15\xadsE\xba\xc0\xd3\xa7G\x0f;\xcf{\x80g\nB\xc4}E\xcf<\xed1~\xeb\xfb\x9eq"g\x91pYW\x01\xfc\r\x95\xb0\xde\xea\x96\xe8;\xee1c]\xe2\xb9\xc2\x9a\xfa\xc81\xb8wyT\xb0MG\x9a\xcfG\xbf\xf2\xdcE\x9e\x96\x7f=G\t\xb0\xceP\xd5P\xfb\x0e\xeb\xa7\x8ccc\xc6\xd8!\xfe>c&\xd5\xc8Q\x8f\x96\xf6\xa9\x88Uco\xee5\xff\x81\xeaD\x1axsX{\xb3j&,\x8dY\x85\xf1>\xc3\xaa\xef\x91\x1ah=\xb8t\\\xf5\xc8\xfbu\xc8\xb7\x1a\xd7\xd5\xf4:\x1b\x86\xf5}\xe2Q\xab\xfd\x99\xba \xec\x13?$~\xe4\xd1\x82G\x8dQ\x83\xcb\xf2\xea\xd8M\x8f\xb5\xf5\x12\x9f\xe5X\xc5LU@\xeb\x10\xcc\xd0q{T\xaf\xeb\xf3\x1b\xf8\xbb\xces\x97\xac5\xea\xf2+m\x85\x0c\xb4\x95\xfd[\\\x85\xbab\x06\xea\x02\xff\x06W\xa3\xaf\x94\x91\xbe\xd5\xa8+g\xa2\xae\xf0[\\6\xff\xebu\xb2\xf5O'
```

This is content of a file within the zip file.

I want to get the contents of this in string format. I know this is a xmlf file (if you look at the output you will find the file name in the header returned).

Basically I am trying to get file contents of  a specific file (archive member) without downloading the whole zip file.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting topic, so you want something like https://github.com/LeversonCarlos/HttpZipStream but in python? Note that this is unrelated to S3.

Comment: python has module `zipfile` but it may need to download all data because some archives may keep information about content at the end of file.

Comment: @luk2302 interesting link - I checked source code. First it reads from stream last 256+ bytes to get [Central Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) in `ZIP` and get position and size of compressed files. And later it reads from stream only data for selected file.

Comment: @luk2302 I have read the Central Directory and fetched the bytes from the remote zip by using the range obtained from Central directory(file offset and compressed file size) ..... which gives the output as provided in the question asked .... What I want to do is to inflate the compressed bytes ... that is where I am stuck ....